# Element moves to the left when I resize the screen

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, resize, minimize

When I make my screen smaller the 'elements' on the screen start moving left and I'm unable to scroll to the left to view those items.  How can I keep the 'element' from moving left when I minimize the screen?

I tried removing all my wordpress plugins and css codes but nothing changed.

Comment: The CSS margin, width, position, and overflow properties are usually the culprits to something wrong with your responsive layout. Without actually being able to see a code snippet or link to the site it would be just a guess as to what is actually your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.